# Connecting to cPanel database with sqlAlchemy

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy, cpanel

I created a mysql database in cPanel, and I'm trying to access it using sqlAlchemy since want to using flask for the application. I have the following code, however it does not seem to connect. Any ideas on how to use sqlAlchemy with the cPanel databases?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: Have you tried using: `engine.connect()`?

Comment: Also, have you missed database name in your connection string? `mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and below code works for me

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()  # Install MySQL driver
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqldb://{db_user}:{db_password}@{host}/{db_name}')
```

at your example you forgot to write database name after host name

[SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine)